# Set game variant before selecting players?

Tags: android, google-play-games

You can set the variant of a turn based match when you create it. I want to use that to keep different version of the app separated because they won't be compatible in multiplayer.

However, setting the variant is not possible for the player selection dialogue (Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent). You can only set it when creating the match, after the player selected the opponents. But how can it be assured that he will only select players that have a compatible version?

My game will always have just two players, so if the invited opponent doesn't have a compatible version then all I can do is to close the match right away after he accepted the invitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to filter the opponent list based on variants, that is used for automatching.

As it seems you have already done - what you need to do is implement a check where the invited player's app version matches up as part of your app logic when you are not using automatch.

As an alternative to closing the match when versions don't match, you could verify the invitee has the app when they are selected and then provide the user with a warning that the other participant has the wrong app version based on the player ID.

If you want to ensure that players only automatch with other players with the same version, that's when you can use the variant.